# Using a Vue composition function in a regular Vue component

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api

The documentation says this is possible but there's no example showing how. How would one go about it?

Answer (score 0):

The `setup()` method is like an add-on to a regular component so we can just include it along with data, methods, etc.

```
function useSomething() {
  // ...
}

const Component = {
  setup() {
    const { out1, out2 } = useSomething();
    return { out1, out2 };
  },
  data: function () {
    // ...
  },
  methods: {
    // ...
  },
}
```